# Run method in Controller on another page before showing results with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord, ransack

## My question

With Ransack, when submit is clicked, is there a way to call a method before displaying the results on another page.

## Summary

I have a page called manualPull that contains a single search_field:

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :Username_cont, "Lookup"  %>
        <%= f.search_field :Username_cont %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Pull & Search"%></div>

<% end %>
```

Basically what I want to happen is when a user clicks on the submit button, we will send a call to the controller of another page (sessions_controller#manuallookupsession) to pull data from our database then show the results on that other page.

## What I tried

I tried adding `url: 'sessions_controller#manuallookupsession'` to `search_form_for` :

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f|, url: 'sessions_controller#search' %>
         <div class="field">
           <%= f.label :Username_cont, "Lookup"  %>
           <%= f.search_field :Username_cont %>
         </div>
   
         <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Pull & Search"%></div>
   
<% end %>
```

I also added the following line to the sessions_controller `before_action :index, only: [:search]`

That almost worked in the sense that it would show the search results in the new page but it would not run the manuallookupsession method in the sessions_controller.  The other weird behavior is that the manuallookupsession method would run every time I refresh the manualPull page but not when I clicked submit.

## Update1:

### session_controller

Here is the code for my session_controller:

```
class PppoeSessionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :index, only: [:search]
  def index
    @q = Session.ransack(params[:q])
    @session = @q.result.order(:username).page params[:page]
    @sessions_to_export = @q.result.order(:username).all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { render text: @sessions_to_export.to_csv }
      format.xlsx
    end
  end
 end
 def search
    puts("TEST")
    @username = params[ 'username' ]
    @sessionsearch = Session.new
    @sessiondetails = Session.new
    if @username
      @sessiondetails = @sessionsearch.pull_user(@username)
      respond_with(@pppoe_session)
    end
 end
```

Comment: Can you show us your `session_controller` ?

Comment: Hey @morissetcl, The session_controller is massive but I heavily truncated the file and only uploaded the abbreviated methods that I believe pertain to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me finally:
In my search_form_for I added a hidden field called search as follows:

```
  <%= search_form_for @q, url: 'sessions_controller' do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :username_eq, "Lookup"  %>
      <%= f.search_field :username_eq %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "search", true %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Refresh & Search" %></div>

  <% end %>
```

And in my sessions_controller I added the following check to my index class:

```
if params[:search] == "true" && params[:commit] == "Refresh & Search"
      search #This is a call to a method
end
```

Furthermore in my search class I was able to retrieve the entered username from the URL (since it was a get request and not a post request) with the following code (you need to `require 'cgi'` at the start of the class):

```
      url = request.original_fullpath.split("/").last
      parameter_hash = CGI.parse(URI.parse(url).query)
      @username = parameter_hash["q[username_eq]"][0].to_s
```

Thanks to @morissetcl for leading me to the correct answer in the comments of your last answer.

I wish there was a way to give you credits for it.

Answer (score 0):

According your given informations, your `before_action` syntax it's a bit weird, can you replace it by this one:

`before_action :search, only: [:index], if: -> { params[:username] }`

In this way you should also remove your if statement inside your `search` method within the session_controller.

Comment: If I remove my if statement within my search method, my code breaks whenever I run my manualPull page even with the new before_action you suggested.  For some reason, my search method is being called every time my manualPull page loads even if the submit button has not been pressed...

Comment: When you submit your form do you see your `puts` in your terminal? (`puts("TEST")`) Also can you try to add on the top of your`index` action the `search` method? (before to call `ransack`) What behaviour do you have?

Comment: I do not see the puts in my terminal on submit but I do see it when I load the manualPull page.. I just tried adding a call to search in the index before the ransack and it worked... search was called. Unfortunately making a call to search in the index is not a viable resolution since the index is called in other instances when we don't also want to make a call to search.

Comment: and if you add `search if params[:username]` couldn't do the job?

Comment: I can't unfortunately since in some instances username will be present in index when we don't want to run search.  Is there a way to pass a hidden Boolean in the search_form_for when submit is pressed and then we could potentially check for that Boolean in the search function

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616025/how-to-pass-parameters-with-form-for-to-controller-ruby-on-rails

Comment: That seems to have done the trick, thanks morris. To be more pressie I added <%= hidden_field_tag "pull", true %> to the search_form_for and if if params[:pull] to the controller.  I'm now facing a new problem.  The data is displayed before the pull is completed. I'm trying to figure out a way to refresh the page from the controller to display the fresh data on the page once the pull is complete